# bring background on opacity 0.5 except pop-up form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I make a profile page and when the user will upload a picture, I will show a pop-up `form`-element. If I bring it visible, the opacity of my `body`-tag, I bring it to 0.5 except the pop-up form and that is my problem. It has also an opacity of 0.5.

```js
document.getElementById('uploadfoto_button').addEventListener('click', function(){
    toonUploadFoto();
});

function toonUploadFoto(){

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.opacity = 0.5;
    document.getElementById('uploadfoto').style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById('uploadfoto').style.opacity = 1;
}
```

```css
#uploadfoto {
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 3;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 600px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px black;
    margin: 5% 10%;
}

img.profiel {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: cover;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}

span.upload {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 276px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://doc.jsfiddle.net/_downloads/jsfiddle-logo.png" alt="Profielfoto" class="profiel"/>
<span class="upload" id="uploadfoto_button">upload image</span>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadfoto">
    <p>Select image:</p>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload image" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: you may be interested in [this](http://codepen.io/jbutler483/pen/JdRrJL) which shows a 'modal popup' design

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See https://jsfiddle.net/7pLxnrrb/1/

You can use an overlay div that'll cover the page with a high z-index and set poup's zindex to something higher.

CSS:

```
.overlay
{
   position:fixed;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

    top:0;
    left:0;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    z-index: 100;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='overlay' class='overlay' style="display:none;"></div>
<form style='z-index:101;'
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';
```

Hide the overlay when the form closes.

Comment: Great tool. This overlay hides the background with the given opacity and on the same time it disables too. The form, or an div-dialog having a greater z-index then can be highlighted and bring in the foreground anywhere in the screen.